# Find the first 5 and last 5 consecutive days which meet a condition and calculate the length of this period

Tags: r

I have a dataset with temperature values from 1989 to 2018, I need to find for each year the first 5 consecutive days in which the `WMean_AVG_TEMP` is >= 5 and the last 5 consecutive days in which the `WMean_AVG_TEMP` is >=  5. Then I need to know the length of this period (number of days), all this result has to be linked to the NUTS code (ITC11) I appreciate any help. heres the example of my dataset.

```
dput(droplevels(head(data,10)))`
structure(list(NUTS = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ITC11", class = "factor"), YEAR = c(1989L, 
1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L
), MONTH = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), DAY = 1:10, 
    WMean_AVG_TEMP = c(4.67658969041876, 3.84797404270322, 0.924227019436549, 
    1.05457654181946, -1.27516988837113, 0.283175108098705, 2.0813951419463, 
    3.62100190622789, 1.76970410697158, 1.71812894277136)), .Names = c("NUTS", 
"YEAR", "MONTH", "DAY", "WMean_AVG_TEMP"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your question is vague. Can you provide sample data and its corresponding expected output?

Comment: `gsl <- tibble( NUTS = c("IT11", "IT12", "IT13", "IT14"), 
               year = c(1989, 1990, 1991, 1992), 
               GSL = c(200, 205, 245, 207))` so I have  my data divided into NUTS (Demographic division of de EU) for each one I have the daily mean Temp since 1989:2017, I need to calculate the growing season, (first 5 consecutives days of the year with a mean TEMP of 5 degrees until the las 5 consecutives day with a mean temp of 5 degrees) at the end I only need a table with the Year, NUTS and # of days (GSL)